# Extracting hashtags AND attached string elements (IF ANY) with regular expressions AND positive lookarounds and lookbehinds in r

Tags: regex, r, string, hashtag, text-extraction

I'd like to create a function in r using regular expressions that extracts hashtags (and one for @'s as well) but checks to see if its a part of a string and return those parts of that string.  I'm still picking up hashtags (and @'s) and so I'm assuming that I'm not picking up pure hashtag strings (#word) because this is after using a function to remove URLs, emails, hashtags, and @'s via:

```
clean.text <- function(x){
  x <- gsub("http[^[:space:]]+"," ", x)  
  x <- gsub("([_+A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[_+A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,14}))","", x)
  x <- gsub("\\s@[[:alnum:]_]+"," ", x)
  x <- gsub("\\s#[^[:space:]]+"," ", x)
  x
}
```

So I'd like to know what parts of the string are attached to the hashtags (and @'s) because I'm still getting hashtags (and @'s) when use the following on my cleaned text.

```
findHash2 <- function(x){
  m <- gregexpr("(#\\w+)", x, perl=TRUE)
  w <- unlist(regmatches(x,m))
  op <- paste(w,collapse=" ")
  return(op)
}


findAT2 <- function(x){
  m <- gregexpr("@(\\w+)", x, perl=TRUE)
  w <- unlist(regmatches(x,m))
  op <- paste(w,collapse=" ")
  return(op)
}
```

Note: again, this is after I apply my `clean.text` function to my text. Would it be something like this?

```
findHash1 <- function(x){  
  m <- gregexpr("(?<=^)#\\w+(?=$)", x, perl=TRUE)
  w <- unlist(regmatches(x, m))
  return(paste(w, collapse=" "))
}
```

> **UPDATE** Example

```
x <- "yp#MonicaSarkar: RT @saultracey: Sun kissed .....#olmpicrings at #towerbridge #london2012   @ Tower Bridge http://t.co/wgIutHUl 
x <-I don'nt#know @It would %%%%#be #best if#you just.idk#provided/a fewexample#character! strings@ #my#&^( 160,000+posts#in @of text #my) #data is@so huge!@ (some# that #should match#and some that #shouldn't) and post@ the desired#output.#We'll take it from there."
```

As for the desired output, I guess something like:

```
[1]  yp#MonicaSarkar:  @saultracey: .....#olmpicrings
```

Or in the second example:

```
[1] don'nt#know if#you 160,000+posts#in %%%%#be fewexample#character!
```

Ultimately, I'd like to see what's attached to the hash tags.

I'd like to use a function or functions that would extract a hashtag (another function or set of functions for @'s) if part of a string in three scenarios and presented my attempt at the first: one that says it must be preceded and followed by one or more characters, another that matches if only followed by one or more characters and a third that matches only if preceded by one or more characters. That is: one that would match the string hashtag only if it's at the middle not if it's present at the start or at the end of a string, one that would match the string only if it's present at the start, and one that would match the string if it's present at the end.

Would three functions like I discussed need to be created for that type of procedure or could it be combined into one?

Comment: It would be best if you just provided a few example character strings (some that should match and some that shouldn't) and post the desired output.

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/NFBZe3).